# Bitwise operations between an integer and an array of bits

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-xor

Suppose I have a c++ array of bits, ones and zeros, and I want to have it bitwise XORed with an integer number, and get the result as an integer. What is the fastest way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you mean a `std::bitset` *and* assuming that it would fit into an unsigned long, then `unsigned long result = your_bits.to_ulong() ^ your_int`;